# Dialog in second case is null

Tags: java, user-interface, null, dialog, switch-statement

I have the following code, the problem is in the last switch, in the first case I create the dialog, I see it on the screen and so far everything is fine. In the dialog there is a button called "btnAddWord2" that corresponds to the second case of the switch, I press it and it recognizes it, the problem is that when I try to make a reference to "dialog" in that case, it takes it as null, which can be a Possible solution?

```java
public class App implements ActionListener{
    
    private Frame frame;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private JsonFileManager file;
    private Dictionary dictionary;
    
    public App() {
        
        dialog = null;
        frame = new Frame(this);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new App();
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        dictionary = new Dictionary();
        int op = 0;
        
        if(frame.getRbtEng().isSelected() == true) {
            
            op = 1;
            
            try {
                
                file = new JsonFileManager(op);
                
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            dictionary.setDictionary(file.getDictionary().getDictionary());
            
        }else if(frame.getRbtFra().isSelected() == true) {
            
            op = 2;
            try {
                
                file = new JsonFileManager(op);
                
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            dictionary.setDictionary(file.getDictionary().getDictionary());
            
        }
        
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("btnTranslate")) {
            
            int pos = dictionary.searchWord(frame.getTextFieldEsp().getText());
            String translation = dictionary.getDictionary().get(pos).getTranslation();
            frame.getTextFieldTrans().setText(translation);
            
        }
        
        switch(e.getActionCommand()) {
        
        case "btnAddWord":
            
            dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            
            break;
            
        case "btnAddWord2":
            
            if (dialog != null && !dialog.isVisible()) {
                
                System.out.println("Enter");
                Definition definition = new Definition(dialog.getTxtField1().getText(), dialog.getTxtField2().getText());
                dictionary.getDictionary().add(definition);
                dialog.dispose();
            }
          
            break;
            
        default:
            break;
        }
            
    }
}
```

First I tried to make a conditional inside that case so that it would check if the dialog is null, and indeed it was because it never executed the code inside the if.
The only thing I hope is that the dialog stops being null and according to the code, the information is set in the text fields of the dialog

Comment: This looks like ancient Java (`Frame`, `Dictionary`) unless you've got custom classes made from say, Swing. Which is it? You `dispose()` the dialog in the btnAddWord2 handler - why? You should probably post the code for `Dialog` too